# I cannot reset to the commit id in engine.version in the src/flutter directory. Is there something wrong?

Tags: flutter, windows, flutter-engine

I want to compiling local flutter engine to debug my app. But when I need to reset commit id that in engine.version to match my local stable sdk channel.

The question is that I can't reset successfully , and get following error:
fatal: ambiguous argument 'cdbeda788a': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git  [...] -- [...]'

So, what should i do to fix it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.